# How to add country field in contact form in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email, billing-address, countries

We want to add a country field in the contact form in Magento 1.9
We need country option as drop down.
Also, we want to send the selected country in contact mail.

My code

```
<?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(false) ?> 
<?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?> <select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select"> 
<option value="">Please choose a country...</option> 
<?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>">
<?php echo $_country['label'] ?> 
</option> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Any help me how to send this country field data in contact us mail?

Comment: We find it's solution. 

<?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(false) ?>
<?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
    <select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select">
        <option value="">Please choose a country...</option>
        <?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>">
                <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Any help me how to send this country field data in contact us mail ?

Comment: Anil, did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to add extra filed, it will automatically go to add in form.

when you submit form and print data in controller's `postAction` at:

> magento1Root/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php

You will get your new filed value Here.
You don't need to change/add anything in the above controller, it is just for checking the value you are getting.

As the above controller is sending all value in `data` to the template, You just need to add:

data.[field_name] in email template.

You can find email template at:

> /var/www/html/magento1938/app/locale/en_US/template/email/contact_form.html

You just need to add:

```
{{var data.[field_name]}}
```

Hope above will help